# items inside div not resizing

Tags: html, image-resizing, css

I'm having a great deal of trouble in getting all items inside a specific Div to resize within that Div, depending on the Div's width (Which is currently width:100%).

I've tried using the display:inline-block but that doesn't seem to work. There has to be something that will work? Basically I have a Div Wrapper that is width:100% and then a Div Container inside that which is a specific width.

The background of a Div inside all of those, has a background image, which I need to automatically resize according to the width. The site resizes down so it is Mobile friendly, which is where I'm getting the issue with the background image being huge still.

The link to the page in question, is here - [Link to Page](http://test.snowflakesoftware.com/)

The below code, is the bunch of Divs mentioned above:

```
#content-home {
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0px;
}

.home_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 320px;
}
```

Hope you guys can help out at all! Just as a warning, it's a WordPress site too but this is specifically a CSS issue. I'm not too sure if there is a Javascript or jQuery function, able to handle this idea?

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: Are you talking about the 5 image boxes inside `.home_slider_bottom`?

Comment: It is working for me... i mean, the scrolling-image gets smaller if the page is resized. What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention guys, I've edited the CSS so when you get down to a certain browser size, it switches to other CSS (Within the same theme.css file) but the section which isn't working is #home_quote_panel and #home_middle_button

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is that you're mixing % and px units for calculating the widths. Try using only % for both widths.

If that isn't the problem, then try using just "width" instead of "min-width". It seems like the "min-width" property might be the issue.